# UIsearchBar input Keyboard Type

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uisearchbar, inputview

Does anyone know how to change the input keyboard type for the searchbar? The code

```
searchController.searchBar.inputView = input
```

doesn't work like in a text field. I have read that the subview of the searchBar is a textfield but I don't know how to access that subview to change the inputView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to display different keyboard than standard, 
Make sure you have assign delegate to keyboard.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, KeyboardDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
 let keyboardView = KeyboardView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 165))
        keyboardView.delegate = self
        let searchTextField = searchBar.value(forKey: "_searchField") as! UITextField
        searchTextField.inputView = keyboardView
    }

    func keyWasTapped(text: String) {
        searchBar.text = text
    }
}
```

**My Custom Keyboard Class**

```
protocol KeyboardDelegate: class {
    func keyWasTapped(text: String)
}

class KeyboardView: UIView {


    // This variable will be set as the view controller so that
    // the keyboard can send messages to the view controller.
    weak var delegate: KeyboardDelegate?


    // MARK:- keyboard initialization
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initializeSubviews()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initializeSubviews()
    }

    func initializeSubviews() {
        let xibFileName = "KeyboardView" // xib extention not included
        let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(xibFileName, owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! UIView
        self.addSubview(view)
        view.frame = self.bounds
    }

    // MARK:- Button actions from .xib file    
    @IBAction func keyTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // When a button is tapped, send that information to the
        // delegate (ie, the view controller)
        self.delegate?.keyWasTapped(text: sender.titleLabel!.text!) // could alternatively send a tag value
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there is any issue ??

Comment: yea it still returns the standard keyboard. I want to change the searchBar input view of the other code you helped me with to be a custom keyboard I create in a UIView.

Comment: i think problem is in your custom keyboard code see my above code is working, if you still have problem update your keyboard class code as well as your main class code

Comment: do I have to import anything to get the KeyboardDelegate?

Comment: KeyboardDelegate is  my custom Keyboard class delegate, i dont know your code so i cannot say for it

Comment: I created a new swift as a UIView and set the value of keyboardView equal to it. It does change the inputView and gives me a gray box. Do I have to program all the buttons or can I create them in storyboard?

Comment: you can create xib for that

Comment: I'm confused. can i set keyboardView equal the xib file directly?

Comment: i am added my keyboard class which loads the xib and display keyboard

Comment: Thanks. It just isn't working for me. The page won't even load.

Comment: Is there anyway to do it without a xib file? It's not leading properly.

Comment: yes you can hide show your keyboard view just assign your view to KeyboardView

Comment: I do that and all I get is a gray empty box. I'm not sure where the problem is.

Comment: if you are getting  an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error with xib, it is probably because you set the view's custom class as KeyboardView rather than do this for the nib File's Owner.

Comment: Wow I didn't even realize I did that. I actually placed it for both the File Owner and the custom class. It finally registered the xib file. Thank you so much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158170/discussion-between-mina-makar-and-jaydeep-vyas).

Comment: @MinaMakar i answered your question in disscussion

Comment: Sorry I don't know why it did that. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to access like this :

```
if let searchBarTxtField = searchController.searchBar.valueForKey("_searchField") as UITextField {
    searchBarTxtField.inputView = input
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me. the standard keyboard still shows up.